# Is it possible to allow access of SA user from specific IP in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a server with MSSQL 2017, and I want to allow SA user access from a specific IP address, but other users can access databases from anywhere. Is this possible?

Comment: _"and I want to allow SA user access from a specific IP address"_ - **why?** - what possible reason could you have - and why can't you create a least-privilege user/login for whatever remote administration you want to do?

Comment: I have found failed login attempts on the SA user. Likely a brute force attack.

Comment: "*I have found failed login attempts on the SA user. Likely a brute force attack.*" - This is one of many reasons why you should disable the `SA` Login and create a differently named Login with the `SysAdmin` server permission provisioned to it.

Comment: This seems like a good question/feature to me. It's not unreasonable to want to restrict access to admin-authorised accounts, e.g. so you need to be on a certain network versus being on a whitelisted IP from some other network.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to allow access of SA user from specific IP in MSSQL?

It's not specified whether you're asking about implementation to be inside of SQL Server or outside.

Inside of SQL Server, while it's technically possible as [Jesse has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387897/whitelist-a-login-and-ip-address-in-sql-server) via login triggers, these are problematic for various reasons. They are executed on each logon, things like large influx of logins, incorrectly written functions, introduced delays, etc., can all cause problems with the login process. SQL Server shouldn't be used as a firewall.

Really, what you want to do is use actual firewall software to only allow connections from the applications and services that are needed.

Comment: But does firewall software allow this sort of fine-grained restriction? i.e only allow user X to log in from certain IP addresses.

Comment: Depending on your firewall, setup, and configuration, yes.